# Imagick: Failed to query the font metrics

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm working on (what should be) a simple script that will add text to an image.  After going over my script several times looking for any mistakes I finally decided to try running a sample from php.net and I encountered the same, nondescript,  error: "Failed to query the font metrics". Here's the code:

```
/* Text to write */
$text = "Hello World!";

/* Create Imagick objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$color = new ImagickPixel('#000000');
$background = new ImagickPixel('none'); // Transparent

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Arial');
$draw->setFontSize(50);
$draw->setFillColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

/* Get font metrics */
$metrics = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

/* Create text */
$draw->annotation(0, $metrics['ascender'], $text);

/* Create image */
$image->newImage($metrics['textWidth'], $metrics['textHeight'], $background);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->drawImage($draw);

/* Save image */
file_put_contents('/tmp/file.png', $image);
```

I can not for the life of me find any information via google about this error. Nor can I find adequate documentation on this method or potential causes of failure. Basically, I'm stumped. If anyone could provide insight or a fix it would be greatly appreciated.

ImageMagic version: ImageMagick 6.6.5-10 2011-04-06 Q16

Imagick module version: 3.1.0b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having similar issues, the PHP Imagick exceptions aren't always the most descriptive. I could have saved myself a lot of time examining the output from the Image Magic application installed on the server first. Just something to keep in mind. To view a list of the currently installed delegates(modules) use the command `convert -list configure` and examine the line that starts with "DELEGATES" from the output. If you encounter the same error, I recommend checking here first. I found I was missing the freetype and ghostscript delegates. After installing the dependancies and a quick recompile of ImageMagick everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried cli version ? is imagemagick installed on server ? if yes
then run a command like

```
system('convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
      -font Candice -pointsize 72 label:Anthony \
      label.gif  ');
```

see if you have imagenamed label.gif in server after running script.
for your reference http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

Comment: I wasn't getting anything back from php so I ran that via the shell and found that I'm missing the freetype delegate. To confirm I ran convert -list configure and found: "DELEGATES     jpeg jng png zlib". So it looks like I need to fulfill that dependency and see if I make any progress... Thanks btw, I put so much focus into finding out what was wrong with my code, that I feel kind of silly that I didn't examine the Image Magic application its self.

Comment: nevermind it happens always imagemagick has lot of modules dependent on many things, once i was stuck at postscript dependency problem and same happened with me too.